# Zip file causes HTTP Error 502.3 Asp Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to download file, however i am getting a HTTP Error 502.3, the problem is that the folder which i am zipping is too big about (300 MB). the zip has not completed zipping. hence the error

i have also tired without await Task.Run: like this:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory($"{tempFolder}\\somefolder", $"tempFolder}\\somefolder.zip");
```

Any idea/hints ?

Thank's

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileAsync()
    {
        string tempFolder = this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + $"\\temp\\";

        #region Zip and delete Folder
        await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory($"{tempFolder}\\somefolder", $"{tempFolder}\\somefolder.zip")); // zip the big folder

        if (Directory.Exists($"{tempFolder}\\somefolder"))
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete($"{tempFolder}\\somefolder", true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to delete {$"{tempFolder}\\somefolder"}");
            }
        }

        #endregion Zip and delete Folder

        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream($"{tempFolder}\\somefolder.zip", FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;

        return File(memory, "application/zip", $"somefolder.zip");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's a timeout issue:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/48

Increate the time out 20min :)

```
<system.webServer>
  <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" ... />
</system.webServer>
```